# Google Analytics for Android: Don't see Demographics and Interests report

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

We are using Google Analytics for android, via the Google play services SDK.

In our reports, "Demographics and Interests reports" do not appear.

We have enabled the demographics reports in the admin.
All documentation and S/O answers we found were about the .js tracking code.

Comment: Have you had any success in the mean time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you update your code ?

From google:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Enable Display Features.
t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
```

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but hope it helps.
From https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872?hl=pt-BR&utm_id=ad